# Polymorphic models like rails in Django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, django-models, polymorphism

In [rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), I can declare a model `:polymorphic => true` and that would be enough to make the model be polymorphic.

But how can I create a polymorphic model in [Django](http://djangoproject.com/)?

I know it's not simple as rails but I need a introduction for doing it in **Django**.

Comment: Maybe if you could describe what the goal is, it would be more useful to the Django devs here. Django allows for model inheritance and model proxies.... but we need to now what issue are you trying to solve with polymorphism?

Comment: just simple thing, like using Tag model for article, event, post, etc.., in rails it's too easy, but in django i have to create it on my own feet, and doing a lot thing (i think), i hope describe it clearly!

Comment: Having tagging support in Django is too easy too installing 3rd party apps, for example [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/). It uses the contenttypes framework, in particular [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Comment: @Guandalino tagging it's just a example, i know that 3rd party apps!, i found solution, with ContentType framework or play with django-polymorphic-models.. tnx

Comment: Check out [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic), which is designed for this use case. It also works when the model is fetched via foreignkeys, ManyToManyFields, etc.. Admin integration and Python 3 support is included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

similar question here: [Double Foreign Key in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162132/double-foreign-key-in-django/5162793#5162793)

Answer is to use the [ContentTypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) framework in django to achieve polymorphic assocations.

Comment: yeah, exactly what i need is [ContentTypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple app called [django-polymorphic-models](https://code.google.com/p/django-polymorphic-models/) that enables you to create polymorphic models with a basic downcast function. It works pretty simply, adds a field that stores the content type of the newly created object. Knowing the content type you can get the child model via object.*lowecase_model_name* (django represents inheritance internally via a `OneToOneField`).  If you use django-polymorphic-models a `downcast` method on the model will give you the child model. Furthermore it adds some similar to methods to the queryset!

Comment: tnx for [django-polymorphic-models](https://code.google.com/p/django-polymorphic-models/), i see it and read the codes, but i'm sure i should play a lot with django document and [ContentType](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Comment: I've been using polymorphic models and it works really well - exactly as you'd expect the models to work in the first place.